# WPF -- Docking Inside MDI

Tags: wpf, mdi, docking

I am not sure it is an appropriate question. But how to do docking inside a MDI. I have one control and I want this control can be dock able inside my MDI. 
I am using WPF VS 2010 with C#.
Any thoughts.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: WPF doesn't really have MDI. Are you using the Codeplex project? Or something else?

Comment: No I am using ActiPro MDI. WPF controls are inside the MDI. I am really confused with docking inside the MDI and the real docking like Avalon provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Actipro Forum
http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Support/Forums/ViewForumTopic.aspx?ForumTopicID=5136
Thanks,